# How to run WINDOWS inside Linux via container (Reverse-WUBI)

Tags: windows, multi-boot, wubi

Would it be possible to install Windows 7 to a virtual container, chainload, and boot it?  This is similar to how WUBI boots Ubuntu inside windows.

It wouldn't be hard to install windows to a partition then use DD to dump it to a file, however booting it would be a problem.  Does anyone know of a solution?  I would really appreciate it.

Comment: DD if= /dev/sda of=windows.iso | frankenstein

Answer (score 0):

hmm, its a little tricky - [you can boot windows off a VHD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/knom/windows-7-vhd-boot-setup-guideline) image, but the only thing i'm sure can boot a VHD is the windows 7 bootloader. If you can chainload that off grub, or use that as your bootloader, you should be able to boot windows off a image. The other issue, of course, is that you need to have the drive on a filesystem that BCD can read.

So, its doable, in theory, but in practice, its fairly pointless for your needs, unless you can get grub to load a VHD (or chainload BCD off grub to boot the image). and somehow all this works on a linux bootable filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)? There is a OSS version for free so you can try.

Comment: I feel this doesn't really answer the question and just provides an alternative that is nowhere near what the question is asking for.

Comment: I agree with @Simon, it would be better as a comment.

Comment: I know, however I am afraid, there is no such app. In fact, there are not so many cases where you need this. You can also use dualboot if you need both systems. I think Wubi was made to take linux nearer to the people. I do not think that linux wants to anyhow support Windows. :-P

Comment: VirtualBox is a Virtual Machine.  Chainloading a VHD runs it nativly.  Thanks to the guy above